# Como adicionar Id ao canvas no Android?

Tags: android, canvas

Eu preciso adicionar um circulo pelo canvas toda vez que clicar em um botão (comportamento idêntico ao Paint do Windows). Porém para mover o circulo clicado sobre a tela eu preciso de um Id. Alguém tem ideia de onde posso adicionar este Id? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isto é criando uma `Custom View`. Sem contar que isto, provavelmente, vai evitar boilerplate no seu código.

```
private class CircleCanvas extends View {

    public CircleCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...
        createCircle(...)
    }

}
```

E quando for criar o círculo no seu código, utilize o método [`View#setId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)).

```
CircleCanvas circle = new CircleCanvas(ctx);
circle.setId(CIRCLE_ID);
```

Comment: boa!!! Acredito que vai resolver meu problema! Obrigado.